# Select element value from html via XPath

Tags: java, html, xpath, jsoup

I've got a html element that looks like this:

```html
<p>
<strong>Popular resonses: </strong>
bat, butterfly, moth
</p>
```

Html contains about all elements with `<p>` tag.

I need to extract `<p>` values (bat, butterfly, moth).

Thanks.

P.S

I've tried to parse with `Matcher` and `Pattern` but it did'n work.
I'm using JSoup as parsing library.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired text by using -

```
Elements el = doc.select("p:has(strong)");
    for (Element e : el) {          
        System.out.println(e.ownText());
    }
```

This will find all the `p` elements in the html that contains also `strong`, and print the text that belongs only to the `p` but not to the `strong` -

> bat, butterfly, moth

If you use `e.text()` instead, you will get all the text in the `p` element -

> Popular resonses: bat, butterfly, moth

If you have only one such element you can also use -

```
Element e = doc.select("p:has(strong)").first();
System.out.println(e.ownText());
```

Which saves you the loop.

Comment: Where is the XPath?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways, depending on just what you want:

If you want the TextNode objects:

```java
String html = """
    <p>
    <strong>Popular responses: </strong>
    bat, butterfly, moth
    </p>
    """;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<TextNode> textNodes = doc.selectXpath("//p/text()", TextNode.class);
for (TextNode textNode : textNodes) {
    print(textNode.siblingIndex() + ": " + textNode.text());
}
```

Gives:

```
0:  
2:  bat, butterfly, moth
```

That's the two TextNodes that are directly in that P. The whitespace before the `strong`, and then the content after.

Another way, similarly to TDG's answer to fetch Elements, but using XPath, is:

```java
String html = """
    <p>
    <strong>Popular responses: </strong>
    bat, butterfly, moth
    </p>
    """;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.selectXpath("//p");
for (Element element : elements) {
    print(element.ownText());
}
```

Giving:

```
bat, butterfly, moth
```

See the [XPath selector guide](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/xpath-syntax), [TextNode](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html), and [Element.ownText()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()) for more details.

If you want an array of values like `{"bat", "butterfly", "moth"}`, you could then call [`ownText.split(",")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).